# Install MongoDB mongodb-10gen 3.0.1

Tags: mono

I have install MongoDB latest version

using  this command:

```
`apt-get install mongodb-10gen=3.0.1`
```

But i am getting error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.0.1' for 'mongodb-10gen' was not found
```

how can i install latest version please help me.

I have already installed MongoDB 2.0.6 version i am try to install latest version.

Thanks & advance

Comment: What O/S are you using? The package and repo names have changed since 2.0.x so you probably need to install `mongodb-org` package or similar. For current instructions see: [Install on Linux](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/install-on-linux/) in the MongoDB manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install mongodb in below guidance, i hope this will help you.

MongoDB’s default data directory path is \data\db.

I have created “data\db” folder to store mongo DB data files in  “D: drive”  and

“log” folder to  store  mongo daemon process  log detail in “D:\mongodb”

In command line, go to “bin folder”  and run below line,

mongod  --dbpath  “D:\data\db”   --logpath “D:\mongodb\log\mongod.txt”   --port
27017

http://www.drtuts.com/how-to-install-mongodb-in-local-machine

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```